# Throw 404 Not Found from PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, error-handling

How can I throw from php an error code 404?
In my htaccess I have a rule that redirect tags to categories, but if after search the category in the DB, if is not exist, how can I redirect to 404 error page and send the correct headers?

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ index.php?lang=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

How can I handle this url?

**site.com/en/this-category-not-exists**

Comment: try this `header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the record does not exist, you can use this code:

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
echo 'This page was not found';
?>
```

If you want to use an external 404 error page, you can use this instead:

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
include("404errorpage.php");
?>
```

---

Alternatively, you can redirect to the 404 error page using

```
header("Location: http://example.com/404errorpage.php");
```

But then you'll have to put

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
```

Into the 404 error page

Comment: Is any way to redirect to my 404.php page? Redirect sending 404 headers?

Comment: @mauriblint you could redirect to the 404 page and put there the 404 Not Found header: I've updated my answer with this alternative

Answer (score 3):

Starting from `PHP >= 5.4.0` you can use [http_response_code function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php) for this:

```
if ($notExistDB) {
   http_response_code(404);
   exit;
}
```